# How to list files and folders together in liferay?

Tags: list, file, liferay, directory

I am trying to list all the files and folders under the root folder of liferay site.

```
QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(WorkflowConstants.STATUS_ANY, QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS, null);
List<Object> list = DLFolderLocalServiceUtil.getFoldersAndFileEntriesAndFileShortcuts(groupId, folderId, null, true, queryDefinition);
```

Is it the right way? How to differentiate the files and folders?

Answer (score 1):

You can get and differentiate all files, folders and shortcuts as following:

```
List <Object> foldersAndFileEntriesAndFileShortcuts = 
    DLAppServiceUtil.getFoldersAndFileEntriesAndFileShortcuts(
        folder.getGroupId(), folderId, WorkflowConstants.STATUS_ANY, 
        true, QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);

for (Object folderAndFileEntryAndFileShortcut: foldersAndFileEntriesAndFileShortcuts) {    
    if (folderAndFileEntryAndFileShortcut instanceof FileEntry) {
        FileEntry fileEntry = (FileEntry) folderAndFileEntryAndFileShortcut;
    } else if (folderAndFileEntryAndFileShortcut instanceof Folder) {
        Folder subFolder = (Folder) folderAndFileEntryAndFileShortcut;
    } else if (folderAndFileEntryAndFileShortcut instanceof DLFileShortcut) {
        DLFileShortcut dlFileShorcut = (DLFileShortcut) folderAndFileEntryAndFileShortcut;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a util called: DLAppServiceUtil with method: getFoldersAndFileEntriesAndFileShortcuts. Check out this this [link](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/document_library/view_entries.jsp) (liferay code).